# Copy file from linux to windows share with C# (.NET core)

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using .NET core for an application running on a Linux machine (a docker container, to be exact)

How can I copy a binary file from there to a windows network share (including username & password)?

All solutions I've found were windows specific, but nothing related to Linux.

Comment: Hi @Pandora, would you be so kind as to share any code you used to solve this, please see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957687/write-file-to-windows-machine-from-linux-net-core-service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about by using [CIFS](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LinuxCIFS_utils) from Samba to mount the share. Once you've installed cifs-utils, you could try something like:

```
 mkdir ~/localMountPoint
 mount -t cifs //server/share ~/localMountPoint -o user=myname,pass=mypassword
```

There's a more in depth tutorial here: https://www.howtogeek.com/176471/how-to-share-files-between-windows-and-linux/

Comment: Thanks Nick! Sure - that's a way to do it, have already thought about that. I was just wondering, if there is any code-based solution too? Would be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

apt-get update && apt-get install smbclient -y

smbclient //IPADDRESS/shared -c 'put myfile.txt' -U mydomain/username%password  -m SMB2

Using P/Invoke